# LEETCODE 349 what's the significance mp[x]=1;

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am looking at LeetCode problem [349. Intersection of Two Arrays](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-arrays/description/):

> Given two integer arrays `nums1` and `nums2`, return *an array of their intersection*. Each element in the result must be **unique** and you may return the result in **any order**.

I solved it using a brute force algorithm, but then I found this solution:

```
class Solution { 
public:
    vector<int> intersection(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        map<int,int> mp;
        vector<int> ans;
        for(int x : nums1)
            mp[x]=1;
        
        for(int x: nums2)
            if(mp[x]==1)
                mp[x]++;
    
        for(auto x: mp)
            if(x.second>1)
                ans.push_back(x.first);
        return ans;
    }   
};
```

And now **my question**: What's the significance `mp[x]=1;` in that solution?

Answer (score 0):

`mp` is a (hash)map, so it stores unique keys and associated values.

In this case the idea is to use the values in both input arrays as *keys* in such a map, and to associate the value 1 with a key when that key occurs in `nums1` and to associate the value 2 with a key when that key occurs in `nums1` and `nums2`. So that is a kind of "counter".

So `mp[x] = 1` registers the value `x` (found in `nums1`) as key in that map and associates value 1 to it, to indicate that this key was found in `nums1`.

In the second loop, the map is used to verify whether a value `x` in `nums2` is present as key in the map with an associated count of 1. If so, then the associated value is increased with `mp[x]++` (so now it is 2).

The final loop iterates all the keys in the map and when it finds that the associated value is greater than 1 (i.e. it is 2), then that key value belongs in the result.